# Python2.x dictobject source code lookdict method explanation

Tags: python, python-2.7

As the doc says, Python dictobject implemented as a hashtable, using [open Addressing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashing-set-3-open-addressing/) to resolve conflict.

When reading source code, there some points , I can't figure out .

**Point [1]**: `if (ep0 == mp->ma_table && ep->me_key == startkey)`, at the head part set epo=mp->ma_table, why compare ep0 == mp->ma_table ? set startkey = ep->me_key at early, why compare ep->me_key == startkey , is there any chance to modify value of ep0 or ep->me_key ?

**Point [2] [3]:** open addressing, often use a prob sequence to dectect where the entry is, so we can implemented as for loop or while loop, why using recursion, what does it mean call  `return lookdict(mp, key, hash);` again ?  As it comment , `The compare did major nasty stuff to the dict:  start over`, what does it mean ?

```cpp
// source code of Python 2.5-2.7
static PyDictEntry * lookdict(PyDictObject *mp, PyObject *key, register long hash)
{
    register size_t i;
    register size_t perturb;
    register PyDictEntry *freeslot;
    register size_t mask = (size_t)mp->ma_mask;
    PyDictEntry *ep0 = mp->ma_table;
    register PyDictEntry *ep;
    register int cmp;
    PyObject *startkey;

    i = (size_t)hash & mask;
    ep = &ep0[i];
    if (ep->me_key == NULL || ep->me_key == key)
        return ep;

    if (ep->me_key == dummy)
        freeslot = ep;
    else {
        if (ep->me_hash == hash) {
            startkey = ep->me_key;
            Py_INCREF(startkey);
            cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(startkey, key, Py_EQ);
            Py_DECREF(startkey);
            if (cmp < 0) 
                return NULL;
            if (ep0 == mp->ma_table && ep->me_key == startkey) {  // [1]
                if (cmp > 0)
                    return ep;
            }
            else {
                /* The compare did major nasty stuff to the
                 * dict:  start over.
                 * XXX A clever adversary could prevent this
                 * XXX from terminating.
                 */
                return lookdict(mp, key, hash);  // [2]
            }
        }
        freeslot = NULL;
    }

    /* In the loop, me_key == dummy is by far (factor of 100s) the
       least likely outcome, so test for that last. */
    for (perturb = hash; ; perturb >>= PERTURB_SHIFT) {
        i = (i << 2) + i + perturb + 1;
        ep = &ep0[i & mask];
        if (ep->me_key == NULL)
            return freeslot == NULL ? ep : freeslot;
        if (ep->me_key == key)
            return ep;
        if (ep->me_hash == hash && ep->me_key != dummy) {
            startkey = ep->me_key;
            Py_INCREF(startkey);
            cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(startkey, key, Py_EQ);
            Py_DECREF(startkey);
            if (cmp < 0)
                return NULL;
            if (ep0 == mp->ma_table && ep->me_key == startkey) {
                if (cmp > 0)
                    return ep;
            }
            else {
                /* The compare did major nasty stuff to the
                 * dict:  start over.
                 * XXX A clever adversary could prevent this
                 * XXX from terminating.
                 */
                return lookdict(mp, key, hash); // [3]
            }
        }
        else if (ep->me_key == dummy && freeslot == NULL)
            freeslot = ep;
    }
    assert(0);          /* NOT REACHED */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Codewise this is C-ish - people in the Python tags will not be able to help, so not sure if tagging this python will address the correct folks - might have more luck with tagging C

Comment: It's C, not C++.

Answer (score 2):

The points you're wondering about aren't related to open addressing at all. Open addressing is handled by the `for` loop.

Look at the line `cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(startkey, key, Py_EQ);`. That line performs a comparison roughly equivalent to the Python code `startkey is key or startkey == key`. This invokes an `__eq__` method that could do pretty much anything, including *modify the dict*.

The `if (ep0 == mp->ma_table && ep->me_key == startkey)` test is there to check that the dict still has the same underlying hash table, and the hash table entry we were looking at still contains `startkey` as its key. If this test fails, the comparison did something weird to the dict, so `return lookdict(mp, key, hash);` recursively restarts the lookup process from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. [The comparison did something weird to the dict],  since compare was a big nested function, can you point out what the magic the compare did ? why A compare function could modify its parameters ?

Comment: "can you point out what the magic the compare did" - the comparison is an arbitrary function outside of `lookdict`'s control. As I said in the answer, it could do pretty much anything. You can write whatever the heck you want in an `__eq__` method.